# How to change Cookies value at runtime

Tags: php

> I have this Php Code at first to check the submit button is clicked or not

```html
<?php
if ($_GET){
setcookie('Body', $_GET['Color'], time() + 24 * 60 * 60, '/');
}
?>
```

> Then I check if the cookies have value or not in class attribute

```html
<body class="
      <?php
        if (isset($_COOKIE['Body'])) {
            echo $_COOKIE['Body'];
        }
        ?>
      ">
```

> And Here is the form code where  I am using bootstrap classes for colors

```html
<form method="get">
        <select class="form-control w-25" name="Color">
            <option value="bg-danger">Red</option>
            <option value="bg-success">Green</option>
            <option value="bg-primary">Blue</option>
        </select>
        <input class="btn btn-primary mt-2" type="submit">
</form>
```

The problem here is When I select a color and click submit I cannot change the background color
at the runtime I must refresh the page or click submit again

Comment: after `setcookie` set `$_COOKIE['Body'] = $_GET['Color'];`

Comment: It works correctly, But can you explain where is the problem at first code @IłyaBursov?

Comment: `$_COOKIE` contains the cookies that were sent from the client. `setcookie()` sets a cookie to be sent to the client, and `$_COOKIE` will get those changes the next time the client sends a request.